# Condicionar BeautifulSoup Python, Web Scraping

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scraping

Buen dia, Agradeceria me ayudasen con este pequeño codigo, Estoy intentando condicionar un BeautifulSoup pero no me imprime el "Else", Soy nuevo en esto y no se si tendria que agregar un codigo que declare el Error del codigo al no compilar para que me imprima el Else, Les dejo el codigo.
Tendria que imprimirme "Error" Porque el valor [10] no existe en la Pagina Web.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

urls = 'https://monoschinos.com/ver/yesterday-wo-utatte-episodio-6'
page = requests.get(urls)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

descarga3 = soup.find_all('a',class_='btnWeb')[10]
if len(descarga3):
    print(descarga3.get("href"))
else:
    print("error")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una opción puede ser agregar un bloque `try - except`, donde vamos a intentar mostrar el elemento, y sí no se puede mostrar, imprimiremos por qué no se pudo mostrar (exceptción arrojada).

```
try:
    descarga3 = soup.find_all('a',class_='btnWeb')[10]
    print(descarga3.get("href"))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print("*"*100)
    print("error")
```

Por otro lado, si quieres mostrar todos los hrefs, te sugiero hacer algo como esto:

```
for i in soup.find_all('a',class_='btnWeb'):
        print(i.get('href'))
```

O por list comprehension:

```
[i.get('href') for i in soup.find_all('a',class_='btnWeb')]
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!, Me ha funcionado :)

Comment: Entando al codigo que me envio para extraer todo los href, Me da un error diciendo que "i" no esta declarado, No comprendo el porque, solo tendria que poner print(i) y tendria que darme todo los href

Comment: ahora lo edito asi se entiende mejor

Comment: Entiendo, Si he usado ese codigo, Hasta que vi que no podia seleccionar la fila que queria extraer en especifico.